# Problem retrieving the image after updating the Access database (System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.')

Tags: c#, wpf

First and foremost, I apologize for my grammatical errors; my first language is Persian (Iran).

I use the following code to insert the image and retrieve it from the Access database, and I have no problem retrieving it after inserting the image.

```
           BitmapImage BM;
           private void UploadButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
           {
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
            if (App.EnumLanguage.Equals(AllLanguage.English))
            {
                OpenFileDialog.Title = "Selecting Image";
            }
            else
            {
                OpenFileDialog.Title = "انتخاب تصویر";
            }
            OpenFileDialog.Filter = "JPG(*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP(*.bmp)|*.bmp|GIF(*.gif)|*.gif|PNG(*.png)|*.png|All Files|*.*";
            if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var IMG = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
                BM = new BitmapImage(new Uri(OpenFileDialog.FileName));
                BitmapImage BitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
                BitMapImage.BeginInit();
                System.IO.MemoryStream MemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                IMG.Save(MemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                MemoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitMapImage.StreamSource = MemoryStream;
                BitMapImage.EndInit();
                BookImage.Source = BitMapImage;
                OpenFileDialog.Dispose();
            }
           }
           private static byte[] ImageToBytes(BitmapImage image)
           {
            byte[] Data;
            JpegBitmapEncoder JpegEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            JpegEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                JpegEncoder.Save(MS);
                Data = MS.ToArray();
            }
            return Data;
           }
           private BitmapImage GetImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
           {
            System.IO.MemoryStream Stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            Stream.Position = 0;
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream);
            BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitImage.BeginInit();
            System.IO.MemoryStream MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            img.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            MS.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitImage.StreamSource = MS;
            bitImage.EndInit();
            return bitImage;
           }
           private void Add_Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
           {
            OleDbConnect.Open();
            if (BM != null)
            {
                byte[] Image_Bytes = ImageToBytes(BM);
                OleDbParameter Parameter = new OleDbParameter();
                Parameter.OleDbType = OleDbType.Binary;
                Parameter.ParameterName = "Image";
                Parameter.Value = Image_Bytes;
                OleDbCommand OleDbCommand_Insert = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into [BookTable](BookName,Publisher,Category,IDNumber,Status,HistoryTaken,RecipientName,ReturnDate,BookImage)values('" + BookName_TextBox.Text + "','" + Publisher_TextBox.Text + "','" + Category_ComboBox.Text + "','" + IDNumber_TextBox.Text + "','" + Status_ComboBox.Text + "','" + HistoryTaken_TextBox.Text + "','" + RecipientName_TextBox.Text + "','" + ReturnDate_TextBox.Text + "',@Image)", OleDbConnect);
                OleDbCommand_Insert.Parameters.Add(Parameter);
                OleDbCommand_Insert.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            OleDbConnect.Close();
           }
           
           \\\ retrieving information from Access Database

           OleDbCommand OleDCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From BookTable Where IDNumber='" + Search_ComboBox.Text.Trim() + "'", OleDbConnect);
           OleDCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
           OleDbConnect.Open();
           OleDbDataReader DataReader = OleDCmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (DataReader.Read())
           {
             BookName_TextBox.Text = DataReader[0].ToString();
             Publisher_TextBox.Text = DataReader[1].ToString();
             Category_ComboBox.Text = DataReader[2].ToString();
             IDNumber_TextBox.Text = DataReader[3].ToString();
             Status_ComboBox.Text = DataReader[4].ToString();
             HistoryTaken_TextBox.Text = DataReader[5].ToString();
             RecipientName_TextBox.Text = DataReader[6].ToString();
             ReturnDate_TextBox.Text = DataReader[7].ToString();
             BitmapImage BMP = GetImageFromBytes((byte[])DataReader[8]);
             BookImage.Source = BMP;
           }
```

But when I use the following commands to update the image and other information, this error is displayed when I want to retrieve the information.

```
                byte[] Image_Bytes = ImageToBytes(BM);
                OleDbParameter Parameter = new OleDbParameter();
                Parameter.OleDbType = OleDbType.Binary;
                Parameter.ParameterName = "Image";
                Parameter.Value = Image_Bytes;
                OleDbCommand OleDbCommand_Update = new OleDbCommand("Update [BookTable] Set BookName='"+BookName_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',Publisher='"+Publisher_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',Category='"+Category_ComboBox.Text.Trim()+"',Status='"+Status_ComboBox.Text.Trim()+"',HistoryTaken='"+HistoryTaken_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',RecipientName='"+RecipientName_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',ReturnDate='"+ReturnDate_TextBox.Text.Trim() +"',BookImage='"+ "@Image" + "'Where IDNumber='" + IDNumber_TextBox.Text.Trim()+ "'", OleDbConnect);
                OleDbCommand_Update.Parameters.Add(Parameter);
                OleDbCommand_Update.ExecuteScalar();
```

System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
Line 6 gives an error

```
                private BitmapImage GetImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
                {
                 System.IO.MemoryStream Stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                 Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                 Stream.Position = 0;
                 System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream);\\System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
                 BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();
                 bitImage.BeginInit();
                 System.IO.MemoryStream MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                 img.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                 MS.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                 bitImage.StreamSource = MS;
                 bitImage.EndInit();
                 return bitImage;
                }
```

In short:in insert command i have no problem to retrieve image but in update command i have problem to retrieve image.

In my opinion, the **Update** command does not save the image properly in the Access database.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you don't use `Stream` for a variable name.

Comment: I used Stream for convert image to bytes , then i used Insert for insert image and i had no problem to retrieve image

Comment: I'm saying that `Stream` is the name of a class, don't use it as a variable too, you risk referencing the wrong thing.

Comment: Your code works for me when the byte array is a proper image, I get the same exception as you when the byte array is not an image.

Comment: It would make sense to clean your code before you continue trying to solve this problem. Remove all the redundant System.Drawing stuff, and use only WPF classes.

Comment: Nobody knows the solution ??? Nobody knows the solution ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray, hooray I found the solution (I found it myself).**if IDNumber data type as be number data type in Access Database , this code works 100%.**

Just Replace this code...

```
OleDbCommand OleDbCommand_Update = new OleDbCommand("Update [BookTable] Set BookName='"+BookName_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',Publisher='"+Publisher_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',Category='"+Category_ComboBox.Text.Trim()+"',Status='"+Status_ComboBox.Text.Trim()+"',HistoryTaken='"+HistoryTaken_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',RecipientName='"+RecipientName_TextBox.Text.Trim()+"',ReturnDate='"+ReturnDate_TextBox.Text.Trim() +"',BookImage='"+ "@Image" + "'Where IDNumber='" + IDNumber_TextBox.Text.Trim()+ "'", OleDbConnect);
```

With the following code (this is how the UPDATE Query command should be written)

```
OleDbCommand OleDbCommand_Update = new OleDbCommand("Update [BookTable] Set BookImage=Image,BookName='" +BookWindow.BookName_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "',Publisher='" + BookWindow.Publisher_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "',Category='" + BookWindow.Category_ComboBox.Text.Trim() + "',Status='" + BookWindow.Status_ComboBox.Text.Trim() + "',HistoryTaken='" + BookWindow.HistoryTaken_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "',RecipientName='" + BookWindow.RecipientName_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "',ReturnDate='" + BookWindow.ReturnDate_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "'Where IDNumber=" + BookWindow.IDNumber_TextBox.Text.Trim(), OleDbConnect);
```

I tested a lot until I finally got the result.
Thanks a lot for your help.